# InvalidAuthenticationToken with /v1.0 but not /beta

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to read emails from Microsoft Graph but I get the following error when calling `/v1.0/me/messages`:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token has expired.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "06e1edb9-cb8d-4371-807e-2795e60b15a2",
            "date": "2019-04-16T12:16:54"
        }
    }
}
```

When I use the `/beta/me/messages` endpoint, however, I don't get any errors, just the expected response.

I'm using the same access token for both requests.

The scopes are:

```
"scp": "Calendars.Read Calendars.Read.Shared email Files.Read 
        Files.Read.All Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Mail.Read
        Mail.Read.Shared Mail.ReadBasic Mail.ReadWrite 
        Mail.ReadWrite.Shared openid profile User.Read User.ReadBasic.All"
```

Does somebody know thy it works with the `beta` endpoint but not with `v1.0` endpoint?

Comment: is your token fresh? the error says it is expired...

Comment: Yes, it is fresh. I used Postman and just replaced "v1.0" with "beta" and it finally worked...
However, I tried it again today and it seems to work now with both URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Mail.ReadBasic only works on /beta. It will throw that error. If you remove that permission, whihc you don't need if you have Mail.Read scope anyway, this error will go away.

We are working on better ways to introduce fine grained scopes like *basic without it causing this experience.

Comment: Is this permission out of beta at this point? I noticed the `Mail.ReadBasic` scope appears in the Azure portal while adding a delegated permission. It also appears on the [Permission Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference) without mention of beta. Trying to add the permission as a delegated scope in the Azure portal, however, gives this error: 

`Unable to save changes. One or more of the following permission(s) are currently not supported: Mail.ReadBasic. Please remove these permission(s) and retry your request. [+tW6R]`

Comment: Yes it is out of beta, we announced that late 2019.

This sounds like a service issue. Could you please raise a support ticket on portal.azure.com for this .